# Not able to save Logs in elasticsearch using Remote PC url with authentication

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, serilog

I have to implement `Serilog` with `Elasticsearch` I implemented it for localhost and it works fine, but when am trying to access Remote PC elastic URL with authentication logs are not saved in `Elasticsearch` also index not created.

I used the following code:

```
.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Url"]))
                {
                    ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.BasicAuthentication(configuration["ElasticConfiguration:UserName"], configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Password"]),
                    OverwriteTemplate = true,
                    AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
                    TypeName = null,
                    BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create,
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                    
                    TemplateName = loggingOutputTemplate,
                    IndexFormat = $"Demo"
                })

                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
```